# Detect EXIF Orientation of an image in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, exif

In my mobile web application, I have a need to examine the EXIF orientation tag of an image file selected using an input type=file control, and this needs to be done on the client side in javascript, before the selected image file gets uploaded to the server.

I have seen several threads similar to this but most of them say to use a library called binaryajax.js to be able to access the EXIF data from the file object.  Unfortunately, simply including binaryajax.js in my project causes an Access Denied error in jQuery 1.7.1, and I have no idea why this is happening. This error precludes me from using this jquery library.  So I am looking for a solution that does not use this library.  Another library I have tried to use is jquery.exif.js and I also get an Access Denied Error Trying to use it.

EDIT:

After much testing, I tracked the cause of the error using binaryajax.js to two links on my home page (which is not the page where I am including the jquery plugin) of the format:

```
<a onclick="$('#home-form-login').submit();"></a>
```

Including these click event handlers on the links is causing the access denied error trying to use the plugin.  Because the links are on my home page, they are also included in every other page I visit, if that makes sense.

How do I get around this?

Comment: The Access Denied error has nothing to do with the libraries themselves, you simply can't call AJAX when testing locally. Try testing your code on localhost or a webserver.

Comment: I disagree with this.  I can and have called AJAX when testing locally.  Also, I have never had a jquery library give me an error like this, so I think it is something about this specific library (binaryajax.js) that is incompatible with jquery 1.7.1. However, I will try testing my code on localhost or a webserver as you suggest.

Comment: I could be wrong, but the way I see it, is if you have the same error from 2 different libraries, it's more likely that it's something on your side rather than the library itself, and I don't think you could get an access denied error from anything you're doing but cross domain ajax.

Comment: All I am doing to get the Access Denied error is to include the script on the page (without even trying to use it for anything).  That is literally all I am doing.  When I get to that page, I get the error. I am merely adding it to the bottom of the page like I do any other plugin:  <script src="~/Scripts/binaryajax.js"></script>

Comment: Update:  I tracked down what is causing the error but still do not know how to fix it.  See the above EDIT for details.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran across this library for image manipulation in JavaScript. It can read EXIF data of an image, including orientation. Worth looking into

https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image